# mysql 5.1.37 query index not being used

Tags: mysql, indexing, explain

I have  a query that is performing poorly.  Server version: 5.1.37-1ubuntu5.1 (Ubuntu)

```
SELECT * FROM `influencers` WHERE (`influencers`.`twitter_id` = 86861293)  LIMIT 1

show create table influencers

influencers  CREATE TABLE `influencers` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`twitter_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`display_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
`created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
`screen_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `index_influencers_on_twitter_id` (`twitter_id`),
 KEY `influencers_screen_name` (`screen_name`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=504126 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1  


explain SELECT * FROM `influencers` WHERE (`influencers`.`twitter_id` = 86861293)  LIMIT 1


id  select_type  table        type  possible_keys                    key     key_len  ref     rows    Extra        
--  -----------  -----------  ----  -------------------------------  ------  -------  ------  ------  -----------  
1   SIMPLE       influencers  ALL   index_influencers_on_twitter_id  (null)  (null)   (null)  553716  Using where
```

The table has 547545 rows in it.

As you can see the explain has the possible key, but not showing it using the actual key.

Any ideas? Seems like this should work and im doing something dumb.

Comment: can you try SELECT * FROM `influencers` WHERE (`influencers`.`twitter_id` = "86861293")  LIMIT 1

Comment: Is that a typo or do you actually just do `where twitter_id` in your EXPLAIN ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since twitter_id is a VARCHAR, you should put the value in quotes in your WHERE clause to avoid any implicit type conversion that may prevent MySQL from using the optimal execution plan:

```
SELECT * 
FROM influencers
WHERE influencers.twitter_id = '86861293'
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: that fixes it, thanks, I guess im passing an int to rails and thats why its doing it this way, I need to research a bit, but this seems to be the problem. I may change it to a bigint

Comment: If all values are bigints, you'll be much better off changing the column type to bigint as opposed to varchar.